# Excel VBA to insert duplicate row below based on drop down menu

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to add to the following **VBA** code, so that when "Did not attend" is selected from dropdown menu a duplicate row is ALSO inserted below the current row within the current worksheet "Details".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)
  'Determine if change was made to a single cell in Column E
  If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    'Determine if Did not attend was chosen
    If Target = "Did not attend" Then
      'If Yes...
      ''Disable Events
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      ''Insert a row below
      ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
      ''Copy, Paste
      Rows(Target.Row).EntireRow.Copy _
      Destination:=Sheets("Non Attendance").Range("A" & nxtRw)
      ''Re-enable Events
      Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have posted?

Comment: `If Target = "Did not attend" Then` probably wants to be Target.Value & `nxtRw)` is not defined in this code. You will want to define it or replace it with `Target.Row + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want. Please try it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 22 Jan 2018

    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "E"), Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
    Debug.Print Target.Address
    ' Determine if change was made in Column E, below row 1 and above last row
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            On Error Resume Next
            If .Cells.Count = 1 Then                ' if change was in a single cell
                'Determine if Did not attend was chosen
                If StrComp(.Value, "Did not attend", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    ' If Yes...
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    .Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert         ' Insert a row below

                    With Worksheets("Non Attendance")
                        Set Rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    End With
                    ' Copy, Paste
                    Rows(.Row).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Rng
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```